# If a page has multiple SVGs, how to find the selected root SVG element, if the text within it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, svg

How to get SVG of clicked element in page with multiple svgs.

I prefer not to go up the parentNode chain till I find it is an SVG node.
Thanks.

Comment: `.closest('svg')`?

Comment: That IS pure Javascript.

Comment: No jQuery needed for `.closest`

Comment: Since this question is specifically about SVG and that SVGElement are special and that there doesn't seem to be a true duplicate for this special case, I will reopen this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVGElement interface exposes an [ownerSVGElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement#Properties) property that will expose just that information:

```js
document.querySelector('rect').onclick = function(evt) {
  console.log(this.ownerSVGElement.id);
};
```

```html
click the rect<br>
<svg id="find_me">
  <rect width='200' height='200'/>
</svg>
```